# How to inject final member in Activity using Roboguice?

Tags: android, roboguice

How to inject final member in Activity without getting the blank final field error?

Can it be done by the activity contractor? Is this the best way to do what I want? If it can, please kindly provide an example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered at another thread: http://groups.google.com/group/roboguice/browse_thread/thread/d1801876b6427428?hl=en